# How to put the table at bottom of the page XML just before footer

Tags: html, frontend, odoo

iam trying to move my table to the bottom of the page just above the footer , can anyone tell me how to do this iam new to programming , i want this table inside this div to be above of the div or bottom near of the page

my code :

```
    <div class="footer">
                <div class="last-page" style="position:relative;font-size:20px;margin-top:0;">
                <table width="100%" class="border-collapse:separate;">
                <tr>
                <td width="33%"><br/><br/></td>
                <td width="33%"><br/><br/><br/></td>
                <td width="300%"><br/><br/><br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left">General Manager</td>
                <td align="center">Accountant</td>
                <td align="right">Receiver</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
             <img class="img img-responsive" style="max-height:500px;width:1000px;text-align:center;padding-right:40px;" src="/account/static/src/img/df_footer.jpg" />
          </div>
```

Comment: i have done with increasing the top

Comment: you can inherit the footer layout using before in position of xpath then you can add your table.